# Why is base64_encode() adding a slash "/" in the result?

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I am encoding the URL suffix of my application:

```
$url = 'subjects?_d=1';
echo base64_encode($url);

// Outputs
c3ViamVjdHM/X2Q9MQ==
```

Notice the slash before 'X2'.

Why is this happening?  I thought base64 only outputted A-Z, 0-9 and '=' as padding?

Comment: Base64 conversion have the / and + also

Comment: just out of interest, why don't you want the `/`?

Comment: Because I am encoding a string to be used as a URL parameter, and the '/' breaks the application because it thinks it's the start of another parameter.

Comment: @BadHorsie — Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to encode strings for URLs, not `base64_encode`.

Comment: yeah, slash was dumb.   just about anything would have been better.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

No. The Base64 alphabet includes A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and `+` and `/`.

You can replace them if you don't care about portability towards other applications.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table

You can use something like these to use your own symbols instead (replace `-` and `_` by anything you want, as long as it is not in the base64 base alphabet, of course!).

The following example converts the normal base64 to base64url [as specified in RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7):

```
function base64url_encode($s) {
    return str_replace(array('+', '/'), array('-', '_'), base64_encode($s));
}

function base64url_decode($s) {
    return base64_decode(str_replace(array('-', '_'), array('+', '/'), $s));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My app will always be PHP-based, so does it matter if I replace them?

Comment: As long as you do the opposite transformation before decoding in your application, no.

Comment: Not such a good idea to use a different scheme than the URL safe encoding as specified in [RFC 4648](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#page-7)

Comment: This is an old question, but I second @owlstead's comment. Just use `urldecode()` and `urlencode()` on the base64 string. If you do this, you're straying away from the standards.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak RFC 4648 *does* specify a different alphabet for base64url that can be created by just replacing characters: `+` becomes `-`, `/` becomes `_`. This is more efficient than URL encoding, which may expand the result quite a lot for certain input (with a lot of bits set to 1).

Comment: @owlstead, thank you very much for letting me know about that. I knew that URL encoding was of course less memory efficient and tripled the message HTTP message size, but I was unaware that the RFC stated those replacing rules as an acceptable standard. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Not working for me, decode generates kind of garbage.

Comment: Is there any reason + and / were chosen?

Comment: What question are you answering with your "No." ?

Answer (score 26):

In addition to all of the answers above, pointing out that `/` is part of the expected `base64` alphabet, it should be noted that the particular reason you saw a `/` in your encoded string, is because when `base64` encoding `ASCII` text, the only way to generate a `/` is to have a question mark in a position divisible by three.

Comment: What about `+`? If and only if  `>` occurs in a position divisible by 3?

Comment: `~` will also produce a `+`. Not sure if there are others.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, you thought wrong. A-Za-z0-9 only gets you 62 characters. Base64 uses two additional characters, in PHP's case `/` and `+`.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing special in that.

The base 64 "alphabet" or "digits" are A-Z,a-z,0-9 plus two extra characters + (plus) and / (slash).

You can later encode / with %2f if you want.

Answer (score 5):

For base64 the valid charset is:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/

the = is used as filler for the last bytes

M.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly related, and enough people above have answered and explained solutions quite well.

However, going a bit outside of the scope of things. If you want readable base text, try looking into **Base58**. It's worth considering if you want only alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 4):

A-Z is 26 characters.
0-9 is 10 characters.
= is one character. That gives a total of 37 characters, which is some way short of 64.

`/` is one of the 64 characters. You can see a complete list on [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: don't forget the a-z too, bringing you to 63 characters :)

Comment: @PaulBain — I didn't, the question did :)